# ¿Cómo hago para que mi tiempo limite se agreguen otros 5 minutos después de que alguien oferte algo en los últimos 5 minutos?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, datetimepicker

Buen día, no se si sepan como funcionan las subastas en línea pero cada subasta tiene su fecha limite con todo y hora, entonces cuando inicia se da una cuenta regresiva hasta la hora que se acabe como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que ocupo que cuando falten 5 minutos para que finalice la subasta si alguien más oferta durante ese rango de minutos se sumen otros 5 minutos mas para que se alargue la subasta otros 5 minutos. Estoy trabajando en PHP y me gustaría saber cómo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de el tiempo limite:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["tiempo_limite"])){
  //arreglo para agregar bandera cuando la fecha concluya
  $indicador = array();
  //obtenemos fecha del servidor
  $fecha_servidor = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  //declaramos el primer valor de fecha y tiempo
  $datetime1 = date_create($fecha_servidor);
  //declaramos el segundo valor de fecha y tiempo
  $datetime2 = date_create($_POST["tiempo_limite"]);
  //sacamos la diferencia entre las 2 fechas la limite de la bd y la del servidor
  $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
  //le damos formato al intervalo que nos regreso la diferencia
  $fecha_restantes = $interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%s');
  $fecha_comparar = $interval->format('%R');
  if($fecha_comparar == '-'){
    echo "Subasta cerrada";
  }else{
    echo $fecha_restantes;
  }
}
?>
```

Este es el código cuando oferta alguien:

```
if (isset($_POST["ofertar"])) {
    //Si el usuario quiere ofertar por un producto
    $oferta = $_POST["oferta"];
    $id_user_1 = $_POST["id_user"];
    $id_sub_1 = $_POST["id_sub"];
    $max = $_POST["max"];
    $fecha_hora_actual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias.

Pregunte el chatgtp y me arrojo esto como podría hacerlo funcionar
Para implementar una extensión de límite de tiempo en PHP que agrega otros 5 minutos después de que se realiza una oferta dentro de los últimos 5 minutos, puede seguir estos pasos: Determine el tiempo restante: realice un seguimiento del tiempo restante para el proceso de oferta. Puede almacenar este valor en una variable o recuperarlo de una base de datos. Verifique si la oferta se realizó en los últimos 5 minutos: cuando se presenta una oferta, calcule la diferencia entre la hora actual y la hora de finalización del proceso de oferta. Si la diferencia es menor o igual a 5 minutos, debe extender el tiempo. Ampliar el tiempo: si la oferta se realizó en los últimos 5 minutos, actualice la hora de finalización del proceso de licitación agregando otros 5 minutos. Puede hacerlo agregando 5 minutos (300 segundos) a la hora de finalización actual.

```php
// // Paso 1: Obtenga el tiempo restante de la base de datos o una variable
$remainingTime = // Recuperar el tiempo restante de la base de datos o configurarlo como una variable

//  paso 2: compruebe si la oferta se realizó en los últimos 5 minutos
$currentTime = time();
$endTime = strtotime($remainingTime);

$timeDifference = $endTime - $currentTime;
if ($timeDifference <= 300) {
    //Paso 3: Ampliar el tiempo 5 minutos
    $extendedTime = $endTime + 300;

    // Actualizar la hora de finalización en la base de datos o variable
    // Guardar  $extendedTime como la nueva hora de finalización
}
```

como lo haría con los datos que tengo ahi

Comment: Tendrías que actualizar la hora límite internamente cuando alguien oferta dentro del tiempo y la página en PHP que tenga abierta quien esté siguiendo la subasta debería refrescarse periódicamente para ver el cambio. O puedes actualizar sólo el dato de la hora de cierre con una petición ajax que modifique ese valor en el HTML presentado.

Comment: @Alfabravo no tendras un ejemplo de como hacer lo por favor?

Comment: Darte un ejemplo tomaría demasiado tiempo por lo extenso de la solución. Trata de seguir las instrucciones de @Alfabravo y si tienes alguna dificultad puntual, creas una nueva pregunta centrada en el problema, así será mas fácil ayudarte.